# New way of referencing deprecated xml prefrence

Tags: android, android-xml

I work with preference xml file as options menu and i use it in my java class like bellwo
but the compiler says its deprecated and add a black line on  addpreffrencefromresource(R.xml.mypreff). what is the new way of coding for it? thank you for helping.

```
package com.bestdiet;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class prefs  extends PreferenceActivity{


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypref);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.help:

            break;
        case R.id.options:

            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:title="پخش صدا"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="checkbox1"
    />
<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:title="پخش موسیقی"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="checkbox2"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: The **new way** is by using a PreferenceFragment. But this can't be used on older devices (API Level < 11). For those ones, you still have to use the **old way** (PreferenceActivity), because the support library doesn't support the Preferences...

Comment: @ArtooDetoo can you tell me now how can i work with that? im testing my proogram on android 2.2 . when i try to open prefs.xml it gives me force close. i think my device is old version but i have exception in it.

Comment: Yes, but it's long (some lines of code), so I have to write an answer. I'm also targetting Froyo as the minSdkVersion. Give me some minutes and I'll show you how I do that.

Comment: thank you for helping. im working on it.

Comment: I also derived it from another site. I took me a bit to make it work. There's a TRICKY PART in the fragment replacement: here **android.R.id.content** instead of your usual fragment placeholder - now it's late here, I'll be back tomorrow. Hope it's easy to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something notable: I just used the same xml preference layout...
But nobody tells you not to use two different files (say prefs_old.xml and prefs_new.xml), to add some of the new features to the (new) PreferenceFragment version of your PreferenceScreen.

This is my PreferenceActivity. It simply checks the build version to see which version of the preferences must be prepared:

```
package com.example.android.scheduler2;

/* ---------------------------------- Imports ------------------------------- */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.ListView;

public final class ACT_Prefs
extends PreferenceActivity
implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    /* ------------------------------ Objects ------------------------------- */

    private Context ctx = null;

    /* ----------------------------- Overrides ------------------------------ */

    @Override
    public final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ctx = getApplicationContext();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
        {
            createPreference_Activity();
        }
        else
        {
            createPreference_Fragment();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // Unregister OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).
        unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // Call base method
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // Register OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).
        registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // Fire base method
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged
    (final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, final String key)
    {
        // ... Do whatever you need to do here ...
        System.out.println(key + " changed!!");
    }

    /* ------------------------------ Methods ------------------------------- */

    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private final void createPreference_Activity()
    {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private final void createPreference_Fragment()
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace
            (android.R.id.content, new FRG_Prefs()).commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

This is FRG_Prefs (the PreferenceFragment)

```
package com.example.android.scheduler2;

/* ---------------------------------- Imports ------------------------------- */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public final class FRG_Prefs
extends PreferenceFragment
{
    /* ----------------------------- Overrides ------------------------------ */

    @Override
    public final void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```